# Boss may think I'm overpaid

Tags: management, salary

I have suspicion that my boss  may think I'm overpaid.  Is there anything I can do to remedy the situation if that is the case?

Hypothetically say I'm 100% sure he thinks I'm overpaid what should I do in this situation?  Work harder?  Also I probably won't get any raises in the forseeable future?

Comment: to much speculation here... Do YOU think you are overpaid? How do you come to this conclusion? How is this your problem what your boss thinks?

Comment: @TorstenLink I mean obviously he has a say in me getting raises and promotion if it was a coworker then I wouldn't care

Comment: Why would your boss think so? You were presumably hired with this salary (or given a raise to this level). Have you been underperforming recently?

Comment: Overpaid in what sense? Paid more than the revenue you generate? More than the market rate for your skills? More than you deserve based on some subjective assessment of how diligently you appear to him to be working? Does he think he can find someone to do the same work for less money? Is he right? Do *you* feel you’re not working as efficiently as you could be? 

These details may seem irrelevant but the right approach to solving this issue depends entirely on what his assessment is specifically and whether or not it’s correct.

Comment: @TooTea nah I didnt get hired by him my old boss works in a different department in the company now he got promoted.

Comment: I think you need to answer the questions that AffableAmbler has posed, in order to get a good answer

Comment: You've not provided anything to go on here.  I'll just say that if your management thinks you're overpaid, that's a bad thing.  Either make yourself more valuable or find another job where you are appreciated more.

Answer (score 8):

> Is there anything I can do to remedy the situation if that is the
> case?

Demonstrate by your continued hard work why you are worth your salary.

Answer (score 0):

I would take in consideration several things :

- are you really overpaid comparing to others?
  Even if you're overpaid, the money you get is a result of a contract and raises(if you got raises).
  If your boss talks only that they pay too much but without talking about performance, it means that the company or the client has changed the budget and he's a little tight.

If the topic "performance" comes up, they can't change your salary willingly, they must have good reasons to state that, mostly happens that they tell "Performance is not in line with your pay" and fire to free money from the budget.
If a plan of improvement comes up, take it and work hard or try to understand the best performing colleagues what they do and learn from them.

I would also try to understand if "performance" is reasonable or the company just decided to earn 20% by the end of fiscal year but this doesn't seem the reason.

A good boss works to make the unproductive employees productive.

Don't lose your hope, you got here with interviews, contract and pay raises in a year or more, you matter.

It happens a lot of times when the old boss changes department, that the new boss doesn't trust you or has other ideas : if your boss didn't tell you nothing or didn't fire you when he was your current boss, I'm sure that you're good worker.

-

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at some recruitment web sites and see what other employers are offering for the same job. You could even call some of the agencies and ask what they think the market rate really is.

Remember that adverts are just the starting point, and there's no guarantee that they'll find people with all the listed experience for the amount they're offering.